# How to use camera in webview react native?

Tags: android, reactjs, webview, react-native

I'm trying to capture image from a webview in react native and then display the same on my html page.

Problem: I cannot access camera and save images from webview.

Solution: I am capturing and saving the images using react-native-camera.

Next Problem: I want to display this above saved image in my webview and then save it on a server.

Note: My page is able to capture and save the data on server when i am opening it in a browser. I am facinf issues with webview in react native.

mywebview.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, WebView, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';

const HtmlPage = require('./index.html');

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    horizontal: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        padding: 10
    }
})

class WebViewScreen extends React.Component {

    webView = {
        canGoBack: false,
        ref: null,
        postMessage: function () { }
    }

    renderLoading() {
        return (<View style={[styles.container, styles.horizontal]}>
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
            <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="#00ff00" />
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
            <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="#00ff00" />
        </View>);
    }

    render() {
        return (

            <WebView
                //source={{uri:uri_source}}
                source={HtmlPage}
                style={{ marginTop: 2 }}
                onMessage={this.msgHandler.bind(this)}
                domStorageEnabled={true}
                ref={(webView) => { this.webView.ref = webView; }}
                renderLoading={this.renderLoading.bind(this)}
                startInLoadingState
            />

        );
    }
}
export default WebViewScreen
```

index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Native Boiler</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hi from html 5</p>


    <img src="file:///data/user/0/com.awesomeproject/files/pic.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Basically i wish to use images stored in my phone and display then in my webview  or access  mobiel  data  from webview.